# How to replace x[t] with Cos[t] in a differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, replacement

If I use /. only x[t] is getting replaced, but x''[t] is not getting replaced.

```
input:= deqn = D[x[t], t, t] + 2 x[t]
output= 2 x[t] + x''[t]
input:= deqn2 = deqn /. x[t] -> Cos[t]
output= 2 Cos[t] + x''[t]
```

Kindly help me in correcting any mistake I am making.

Comment: Would `deqn /. {x[t] -> Cos[t], x''[t] -> -Cos[t]}` work, or do you want something more automated?

Comment: Doesn't `x->Cos` work?

Comment: yes sir...now x->Cos is working. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

You could try any of the following:

1)
Simply substitute `Cos` for `x`

```
deqn=D[x[t],t,t]+2 x[t]
deqn2=deqn/. x->Cos
```

Yours wasn't working because `x''[t]` is not literally `x[t]`.

2)
Change the definition of `x` in a `Block` and use that

```
deqn=D[x[t],t,t]+2 x[t]
deqn2=Block[{x = Cos}, deqn]
```

3. 

Define a function for your equation which accepts a variable `Head`.

```
deqnB[x_]=D[x[t],t,t]+2 x[t]
deqn=deqnB[x]
deqn2=deqnB[Cos]
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Now its clear for me

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above suggestions, if you do ever need to replace `x'[t]` or `x''[t]` or the like, it can be done via

```
x'[t] /. Derivative[n_][x][t] -> Derivative[n][Cos][t]

(* -Sin[t] *)
```